# My economy system isn't working, and I can't identify an error

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I've been trying to make an economy system in discord.py. However, the system is not working whatsoever. Whenever I type in the !balance command it doesn't send an embed at all. It doesn't even give an error. Here is my code:

```
@client.command()
async def balance(ctx):
  user = ctx.author
  await open_account(ctx.author)

  users = await get_bank_data()



  wallet_amt = users[str(user.id)]["wallet"]
  bank_amt = users[str(user.id)]["bank"]

  embed=discord.Embed(title=f"{ctx.author.name}'s Balance")
  embed.add_field(name="Wallet:", value=wallet_amt, inline=False)
  embed.add_field(name="Bank:", value=bank_amt, inline=False)

  await ctx.send(embed=embed)

async def open_account(user):
    users = await get_bank_data()

    if str(user.id) in users:
        return False
    else:
        users[str(user.id)] = []
        users[str(user.id)]["wallet"] = 0
        users[str(user.id)]["bank"] = 0

    with open("bank.json", "w") as f:
        json.dump(users, f)
    return True

async def get_bank_data():
    with open("bank.json", "r") as f:
        users = json.load(f)
    return users
```

Can anyone help me identify the error? I'm quite new to discord.py

Comment: Does bank.json have any contents in it?

Answer (score 0):

Your `open_account()` function's logic will always return True even if the `if` condition passes because the indentation is backed off. If it is linked with the way you retrieve the data this might be your issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
@client.command(aliases=['bal'])
async def balance(ctx):
    await open_account(ctx.author)
    user = ctx.author

    users = await get_bank_data()

    wallet_amt = users[str(user.id)]["wallet"]
    bank_amt = users[str(user.id)]["bank"]

    em = discord.Embed(title=f'{ctx.author.name} Balance',color = discord.Color.red())

    em.add_field(name="Wallet Balance", value=wallet_amt)
    em.add_field(name='Bank Balance',value=bank_amt)
    await ctx.send(embed= em)
async def open_account(user):

    users = await get_bank_data()

    if str(user.id) in users:
        return False
    else:
        users[str(user.id)] = {}
        users[str(user.id)]["wallet"] = 0
        users[str(user.id)]["bank"] = 0

    with open('mainbank.json','w') as f:
        json.dump(users,f)

    return True
async def get_bank_data():
    with open('mainbank.json','r') as f:
        users = json.load(f)

    return users
```

This should work change the json file name to the correct one,
one important thing , **check your saving functions and file content too**

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.